# Call to a possibly undefined method through a reference with static type Class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I wrote a singleton class to keep track of some variables across my application.

I am getting a syntax error that I can't figure out, I am sure that I am missing something simple but it's been one of those days. Anyone see something wrong with my code?

The error is 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method setResult through a reference with static type Class.

My function in my singleton class

```
public function setResult(resultNumber:int, value:int): void
    {
        switch(resultNumber)
        {
            case 2: { this.result2 = value; break; }
            case 3: { this.result3 = value; break; }
            case 4: { this.result4 = value; break; }
            case 5: { this.result5 = value; break; }
            case 6: { this.result6 = value; break; }
            case 7: { this.result7 = value; break; }
            case 8: { this.result8 = value; break; }
            case 9: { this.result9 = value; break; }
            case 10: { this.result10 = value; break; }
            case 11: { this.result11 = value; break; }
            case 12: { this.result12 = value; break; }
            case 13: { this.result13 = value; break; }
            case 14: { this.result14 = value; break; }
        }
    }
```

My function call in my mxml page

```
            if(chkBox1.selected == true)
            {
                utils.Calculation.setResult(2,1);
            }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you singleton is the Calculation class, are you missing your getInstance call?

```
utils.Calculation.getInstance().setResult(2, 1);
```

A good actionscript singleton pattern:

```
package com.stackOverflow
{
    public class MySingleton
    {
        public function MySingleton(lock:Class)
        {
            if(lock != SingletonLock)
                throw new Error("This class cannot be instantiated, it is a singleton!");
        }
        private static var mySingleton:MySingleton;

        public static function getInstance():MySingleton{
            if(mySingleton==null)
                mySingleton = new MySingleton(SingletonLock);
            return mySingleton;
        }
        public function setResult(resultNumber:int, value:int): void{
        //...
        }
    }
}
class SingletonLock{}
```

Edit: getInstance() example for the Calculation class:

```
private static var calculation:Calculation;
public static function getInstance():Calculation{
    if(calculation==null)
        calculation = new Calculation(SingletonLock);
    return calculation;
}
```

Comment: Using your method results in Error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Calculation at the getInstance() function declaration line

Comment: Rename MySingleton in Calculation. This is only an example.

Comment: public static function getInstance(): Calculation{
   if(Calculation==null)
    Calculation = new Calculation();
   return Calculation;
  }

Comment: Regardless of the error I was missing the getInstance() so thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
public static function setResult(...)
```

Comment: If I use static then I can not use the this. keyword to access my variables

Comment: OP, you'll also need to remove the references to `this` in the function if you're making it static.